# TCP Client Socket. Connect and wait for input stream

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a wifi sd card which sends me TCP packages with information about new images on the memory after I shoot a photo with the camera.

On the terminal I can read the inputstream with this netcat command. netcat connects to ip 192.168.11.254 and listen on port 5566. the second line is the image path which I receive.

```
$ nc 192.168.11.254 5566
>/mnt/sd/DCIM/109_0302/IMGP0101.JPG
```

On my app I have a Java client socket which is connected to the same ip and port. But I don't receive the inputstream like in netcat, nothing happens.

```
void startListenForTCP (){
    Thread TCPListenerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Boolean run = true;
            String serverMessage = null;
            InetAddress serverAddr = null;

            try {
                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.11.254");
                Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5566);

                try{
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    while (run) {
                        serverMessage = in.readLine();
                        mHandler.post(new DisplayToast(context, "TCP : " + serverMessage));
                    }

                } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                    mHandler.post(new DisplayToast(context, "UnknownHostException"));

                } catch(IOException e) {
                    mHandler.post(new DisplayToast(context, "IOException"));
                } finally {
                    clientSocket.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    TCPListenerThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this may it works

### Step 1

Remove these two lines:

```
serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.11.254");
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5566);
```

Add this line:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.11.254", 5566);
```

### Step 2

Remove this code:

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    while (run) {
        serverMessage = in.readLine();
        mHandler.post(new DisplayToast(context, "TCP : " + serverMessage));
    }
}
```

Add this code:

```
try {
    char[] buffer = new char[2048];
    int charsRead = 0;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    while ((charsRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        String message = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
        Log.e("In While", "msg :"+message);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The javadoc of [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) states:

> Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

If the card doesn't send some kind of end of line, this method will never return. Try to read directyl from `clientSocket.getInputStream()`. This doesn't do any buffering.

Comment: good explanation. this was the reason why I didn't received the massage.

Comment: Bash on-liner is `echo -e "/mnt/sd/DCIM/109_0302/IMGP0101.JPG\r" | nc 192.168.11.254 5566`